# \section using characters instead of numbers?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

The `\section{something}` enumerates from 1 to N-1. I was wondering if instead the `\section{something}` could print letters like

A. Section
B. Section
...etc.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}`? What was the syntax again?

Comment: Sigh, how many times is this question asked? :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think the answer is *42*.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Rather `$42^{42}$` times ;-)

Comment: What does numbering from `1` o `N-1` mean. Do you use only `N-1` sections? What is `N`?